# In VS Code rulers are not drawn for Haskell files

Tags: visual-studio-code, haskell, rulers

I have added vertical rulers to VS Code in the `settings.json` file like this:

```
    "editor.rulers": [
        40,80],
```

This works, e.g. for Python files but strangely not for Haskell files. (I am using the usual Python and Haskell extensions.)

Here a screenshot of VS Code with Haskell files:

[image: Haskell code has no rulers]

Any idea how I can make the rulers visible for Haskell as well?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Rulers do work in my vscode with haskell

Comment: I add a screenshot.

Comment: adn  you have two rulers at 40 and 80?

Comment: @lsmor Yes, I have rulers at 40 and 80 cols - just to make testing of the rulers easier.

Comment: Whatever it is is not related with the haskell extension. rulers is a vscode thing independent from the extension. Are you sure your _global_ setting uses rulers? or you use rules in local settings in your python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any `rulers` setting in any of the normal settings files. However, in my current `project.code-workspace` file I had the lines:

```
        "settings": {
                "editor.rulers": []
        }
```

which overwrote the ruler preferences in the settings files!

When I took these lines out of the workspace file everything went back to normal and the ruler appeared as expected

*Note:* Because the settings were stored in the workspace file, other projects (like my python projects with other or no workspace file) were not affected. -- So it appeared to me that the issue is Haskell-related, but infact it was only related to my Haskell workspace file.